# Disable or change Windows 10 password expiration reminders

Tags: windows-10, passwords, active-directory

I'm on a corporate laptop, and they have a fairly short password expiration policy, such that about half the time, I get a reminder to change my password long before it's actually expired. Seems like a week or two before it expires I start getting warnings every time I log in and it's pretty annoying. I can't disable password expiration because it's a group policy set by the domain, but I'd like to at least reduce how early it starts giving warnings. When I google around for how to disable or change just the warning itself, all I find are pages showing how to disable the actual password expiration for local users, which isn't what I'm looking for.

Comment: Warning a week or two before expiry is fairly standard. Could you just not change your password? Why do you need to wait they extra 2 weeks?

Comment: You will have to talk to your IT Administrator to make the require changes.  You cannot change when the password expiration notice will be display as a non-privilege user.

Comment: @Smock My password expires every 30 or 60 days (can't remember exactly) and that's bad enough to have to constantly remember a new password without having to change it 2 weeks earlier every time.

Comment: @Ramhound I am an administrator on the laptop, if that makes a difference.

Comment: @IsaacFreeman Settings like these are usually domain level, so being an admin on the laptop won't make a difference, unless it's not on the domain.